# Custom URL redirect in WP

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, redirect, page-template, wp-redirect

I am trying to make my own redirect page for external link.

**My target**

My target is that, when a user open the link `www.mysite.com/wp/GoTo/?URL=www.google.com`, the browser open the page `www.google.com`

**What I have done**

I have saved the following `GoTo.php` file inside the folder `wp-content/themes/theme-name/`:

```
<?php


/*
Template Name: GoTo
*/

/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package theme-name
 */

$url = $_GET["URL"];

// Remove all illegal characters from a url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== true) {
    header("location: " . $url);
    exit;
} else {
echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
?>
```

then I have created a page with the URL `www.mysite.com/wp/GoTo/` with template `GoTo`.

At the moment:

- if I open `www.mysite.com/wp/GoTo/?URL=xyz` I get a 404 error (instead of the message "URL is not valid";
- if I open `www.mysite.com/wp/GoTo/?URL=www.google.com` I get a 404 error (instead of open google.com).

How can I fix this?
Unfortunately I can't refer directly to the php page. In other words I can't write in the browser `www.mysite.com/wp/wp-content/themes/theme-name/Z_GoTo.php?URL=www.google.com`, as the mod rewrite contains rules against it.

**Disclamer**

I know that there are several questions about redirect in WP, but none of them is about a situation like mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this expression:

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== true
```

which should or could be written as just:

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
```

Because the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for `filter_var()` says:

> Returns the filtered data, or `FALSE` if the filter fails.

which means, with a valid URL, `filter_var()` does *not* return a boolean; hence `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== true` never evaluates to `false`. I.e. all URLs would be seen as valid.

So the full code, without the comments:

```
$url = $_GET["URL"];

// Remove all illegal characters from a url
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    header("location: " . $url);
    exit;
} else {
    echo("$url is not a valid URL");
}
```

### Additional Note

To redirect to an external URL/domain, you need to specify the protocol — e.g. `http://`. Try below `header()` code and you'd understand it:

**Code #1:**

```
// Has the protocol; this would always redirect to http://www.google.com
header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' );
exit;
```

**Code #2:**

```
// Protocol not specified; redirects to a URL on your site. For example,
// if you're on http://your-site.com/path, then you'd be redirected to
// http://your-site.com/path/www.google.com
header( 'Location: www.google.com' );
exit;
```